# Nopcommerce Plugin View: CSS and JavaScript Files Not Found (404)

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, nopcommerce

**A Little Background**
We have been doing some restructuring with regards to how we work with nopCommerce to keep things more maintainable. Previously, we have been using the theme system to take care of our views, scripts, css, and images. We are now, however, moving all of this to our primary plugin called "Nop.Plugin.Wca.WE", and this is where a very strange issue is occuring for me.

**My Problem**
I have moved everything over and updated all references, paths, etc. so that things should be working just fine, but that is only partially the case. My controller is able to return the views just fine, but the views cannot add any CSS or JavaScript files as it says they "cannot be found (404)" in the browser's inspector. I have kept the exact same syntax that I was using when it was in the "Themes" folder (where it was working), I have only changed the path:

```
Html.AppendCssFileParts("~/Plugins/Nop.Plugin.Wca.WE/Contents/css/ProductDetails/styles.css");

Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Plugins/Nop.Plugin.Wca.WE/Scripts/ProductDetails/ProductDetailsTooltips.js");
```

Error Message:

```
http://localhost:15636/Plugins/Nop.Plugin.Wca.WE/Contents/css/ProductDetails/styles.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

http://localhost:15636/Plugins/Nop.Plugin.Wca.WE/Scripts/ProductDetails/ProductDetailsTooltips.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

**The Paths Are Correct and The Files Exist**
The first thing this would make you think is "well there must be something wrong with the path", however, this cannot be the case as I have verified this with the following code in the same file:

```
@HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath
```

This outputs:
"D:\TFS_Clean2\WCA B2B Online Store\nopCommerce_B2B_3.80\Presentation\Nop.Web\ "

which proves that the root "~/" is in fact in Nop.Web as expected.

And also:

```
@File.Exists(@"D:\TFS_Clean2\WCA B2B Online Store\nopCommerce_B2B_3.80\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Wca.WE\Scripts\ProductDetails\ProductDetailsTooltips.js")
```

which outputs "True", so the file does exist in this exact location.

I feel that it is also worth mentioning that there are many other calls in this view file that return partial views using the same pathing logic and these all work as expected, here is one example:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Plugins/Nop.Plugin.Wca.WE/Views/ProductDetails/_ProductPrice.cshtml", Model.ProductPrice)
```

**What I've Tried**
-I have tried the different method variations "AddCssFileParts()", "AddScriptParts()", etc. None of these have had an effect.

-There is a small section in the documentation showing how to add these files that uses a little bit of a different syntax: http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/nc/Adding+CSS+and+JS+resource+files+into+nopCommerce+Plugin
I have tried this with no change in behavior.

-I have tried altering the path in small ways such as removing the "~/" and removing the file extensions.

-I have refreshed my browser's cache.

This seems like it should be such a small problem, but I have been troubleshooting it for hours to no avail. Hopefully somebody here can shine some light on the situation for me. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, there was a setting in the plugin's web.config file that was blocking access to the files:

```
<handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</handlers>
```

I believe that this is intended to restrict access to Views but since it was in the plugin's config file I guess it was restricting the other files as well, although oddly enough like I mentioned in my post, I was able to access the views just fine so I'm not too sure whats going on there.

Comment: Congrats on solving your own problem friend!